# Cover letter: Offer to catch up on things I might be missing, before starting or before an interview?

Tags: cover-letter, student, part-time

I would like to get an interesting part-time position alongside studying.
However, I have encountered interesting positions where I feel I might be missing some requirements. Either I am missing a non-strict requirement that they mention on the offer, or I am suspecting I'm missing something, but do not know what exactly that would be. So by offering to catch up, I'm at the same time asking *what* to catch up on.

For this I would be willing to spend some time (let's say up to four days) to learn about a topic that I might be missing. This is also under the assumption that whatever the topic will be, it's probably interesting as it is related to this interesting part time position.

*Should I make such an offer? For instance:*

> 1: "I do not yet know [non-strict requirement X] - if desired, I can teach myself the basics before a first interview."

or

> 2: "For any topic related to [X]: I'd be happy to teach myself the basics, within a manageable amount of time, before [a first interview / starting]."

Context: Such job offers are often not specific about the exact methodology that will be used in the job, so I am often not sure whether my background fits their expectation, or whether they would much prefer someone who already took course [Y].

Downsides I see:

- I tell them that I'm not sure whether I know everything they would like me to know
- It shows uncertainty
- I might end up studying something boring for a day before deciding that this job is not for me and cancelling the interview
- If there are better candidates, it will not actually make a difference. A few days will not teach me what someone else learned in the course of months.

Possible upsides:

- It increases my value for them - I'm obviously hoping this might make them more likely to interview and hire me, in case I'm missing something they want.
- It shows my interest (could it be interpreted as despair though?)
- The time spent can also be beneficial to me, because I get to learn something new - especially if they point me to good resources. It might even be useful for another job application in the future.
- It might tell me more about the job before starting.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to workplace.SE! Putting an "Edit" section into your question makes it hard to read, so I incorporated it into your Q. If you want to alert readers to an update, that's what comments are for.

Answer (score 6):

Forget including that part in your cover letter.

If four days is all that you need. Just send your resume now and start studying for a couple of days as soon as you can.

It may take them a few days to answer and it may take them a few days to schedule your first interview. And scheduling is a collaboration, you get to agree whether you want to interview this week or next week.

Comment: I would add that you can mention during the interview that you didn't know X but you taught yourself the basics.

Comment: Thank you, that answers whether to include the first point or not. 
I'm still not clear about the second case (I should have made the distinction clearer): Do I ask them to tell me _what_ to prepare for, offering at the same time to catch up on it?

Comment: @dasWesen, For my own technical interviews for being an Android software developer, I usually ask what I am going to be tested on, or how I should prepare, and they typically give me the same answer: Android core concepts. And data structures and algorithms.  In your case, I have no idea what topic it is, or what profession you're in. But definitely, you should ask.